# Augmented Reality applications using Java API

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I am currently new to augmented reality programming and i would like to ask a question regarding AR app. [I have downloaded "Augmented Reality" app from the play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ar.augment&hl=en) . Using Augmented Reality app, I could be able to view some 3D model objects such as front view, back view, left and right side views. I have taken a print out of Universal tracker sheet so with the help of Universal tracker, I could be able to view some 3D model objects.

For an example, car or bike can be placed on a universal tracker (printed sheet) and then the objects can be viewed in a graphical views. I can understand that with the help of "Augmented Reality" concept,  the objects can be viewed in a 3D graphic model with their actual size that is integrated in real time environment. I could also be able to understand that Universal tracker is a software and should capture the objects then with the help of some software those objects can be rendered and viewed as a 3D model.

When I researched about Augmented Reality technology, could be able to see many open source library and engines such as AR-Tool kit, Mixare so on. By using Wikitude SDK can achieve this.

I know that AR provides API for interacting with a camera and it supports OpenGl graphics so as a Java/Android developer how can I begin with or develop an AR applications for Android?

I referred to [Wikitude SDK with Android and Java](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/Reference/Android%20Reference/html/index.html).

[Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/web/imagerecognitionand3d.html)

As far, I know that AR tool kit is written in Java. As a Java Android Developer, how to work with Wikitude SDK to develop such apps as I mentioned above here? Is there any sample apps or tutorial based on Android with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the Wikitude SDK but I recently created an AR app for Android using the [Qualcomm Vuforia SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android).  I used Vuforia to handle the AR functionality and rendered models from obj files onto the image targets using OpenGL ES 2.0.  The Vuforia SDK was excellent; it is free and developed by Qualcomm so it is high quality.  There are tutorials at the Vuforia developers site and several demo apps (with source code) that come with the SDK.